# What does "steamrolling concessions" mean exactly?

Tags: meaning

There is a term that is used in conversation that I can't understand. What does this sentence mean, "don't steamroll concessions"?

Comment: What's the context of the conversation that this came up in?

Comment: [Steamroll](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/steamroll) as a verb is in good dictionaries. It can be slightly ambiguous as it means both to crush and to bring forward forcefully.

Comment: Similar to [bulldoze](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bulldoze).

Comment: Perhaps you should look at a picture of a steamroller.

Answer (score 1):

The term is about argument strategy. I had never heard the term, so I appreciate the question. Will help me to be more aware of my tendency to interrupt, at times.

https://twitter.com/FamManFitness/status/1591033471408873473

"4. Don't Steamroll Concessions

Acknowledge the other person's points, especially when they try to find common ground, keeps the conversation civil. If you are willing to agree and acknowledge their perspectives they are more likely to mirror the behavior."

---

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XGVUHPl4YuI&t=281s

In the info below the video, it is #4.

"Steamrolling concessions keeps you from reaching common ground with the person you're talking to."

In the clip, Andrew is trying to 'concede' that that Piers had made a good point, but is interrupted over and over (steamrolled).

"If there's anyone else listening, it also makes it harder for them to register that you've made a good point."